# Magento2.3.5 Custom checkout field custom validation Amazon Error

Tags: checkout, custom-field, mixins, magento2.3.5

I have a custom field and customScope added with LayoutProcessor which works fine!

But I need to add custom validation stop submission if my custom doesn't meet the requirements :

Is just trowing amazon error for some reason:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setShippingInformationAction(...).done is not a function
    at setShippingInformationAmazon (shipping.js:60)
    at UiClass.setShippingInformation (shipping.js:76)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (knockout.js:4640)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5232)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4884)
```

no matter where I stop the form from submitting either `Vendor_Module/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin`:

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
            if(shippingMethod['method_code'] === 'vendor_shipping') {
               console.log('vendor_shipping');
               return false;
            }
            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

Or `Vendor_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default`:

```
....
  return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                console.log('OVER HERE');
                var payload;

                if($('select[name="vendor_selector_drop_down"]').val() === '') {
                    console.log('invalid here');
                    return false;
                }
                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }
       ...
```

Why is Amazon interfering with it I haven't enable it ? Could this be a bug anyone else doing something similar and have seem this and any advice appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Juliano Vargas Have you got the answer for this above issue, currently I'm faced the same issue in magento V2.4.5